# device not open error + QIODevice::write

Tags: c++, qt, client-server, tcp

I get the error:

> QIODevice::write (QTcpSocket): device not open. 
>   After trying , I think problem is passing parameter server->nextPendingConnection() into object. Can someone has idea how to do it correctly?

My understanding is that object for `socketClient` is not initialised properly. 
I'm using Ubuntu with Qt.

I am implementing server using Qt. The server part has two classes based on `QTcpServer` and `QTcpSocket`. 
say `Server` and `SocketClient`.
I am creating object of SocketClient in server and for testing purpose I opened telnet session and wants to see that server write "hello" on terminal. But somehow its not working. Can someone please advice me where I am making mistake.

```
Server::Server(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
  server_obj = new QTcpServer( this ); 
}

void Server::startServer()
{
  connect( server_obj, SIGNAL( newConnection() ), this, SLOT( incomingConnection() ) );
  if( !server_obj->listen( QHostAddress::Any, 9999) )
  {
    qDebug() << " Server failed to get started";
  }
  else
  {
   qDebug() << " Server started"; // this is successful
  }
}


void Server::incomingConnection()
{
  socketforClient = new SockClient( server_obj->nextPendingConnection() );// has a doubt on nextPendingconection??

  //only for testing remove it
  socketforClient->writeToClient();
}
```

Class for Client

```
 * Description: Its a constructor.I have changed default constructor to add QTcpSocket* object in parameter.I used this constructor in  void Server::incomingConnection()
 */
SockClient::SockClient(QObject *parent,QTcpSocket* socket ) : QObject(parent)
{
  socketClient = new QTcpSocket( socket );

 qDebug() << " we are in constructor of 1st sockclient ";

}



// this is for testing purpose only

void SockClient::writeToClient()
{
   socketClient->write(" hello world\r\n");
   socketClient->flush();
   socketClient->waitForBytesWritten(3000);

}
```

//header file of SockClient

```
class SockClient : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:

 explicit  SockClient( QObject *parent, QTcpSocket* socket= 0 ); // I have created
    void writeToClient(); // This is for testing purpose
 ~SockClient();
signals:

private slots:
  void readClient();

private:
  void sendResponsetoMops();

  QTcpSocket *socketClient;

  quint16 nextBlockSize;

public slots:
};
```

Comment: Does the SockClient constructor have a default argument for it's second parameter (`socket`)?

Comment: @Jan 1, no , it does not have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use:

```
socketClient = new QTcpSocket( socket );
```

Try to use following code instead:

```
socketClient = socket;
```

And use
 `socketforClient = new SockClient(this, server->nextPendingConnection() );`

instead of

```
 socketforClient = new SockClient( server->nextPendingConnection() );
```

Comment: No it doesnt work infact the program crashes and it makes sense because socketClient = socket , goes out of scope.

Comment: Could you please check at first that your server app listening on port: 9999. On Linux try: netstat -nap | grep LISTEN

Comment: Well Murad, I tried something else and it works but thats not I want. What i did was -> 1) in function void Server::incomingConnection() I added following  line                                                                           QTcpSocket *socket = server->nextPendingConnection();

      socket->write("Hello client\r\n");
      socket->flush();

      socket->waitForBytesWritten(3000);

      socket->close();
}

Comment: And it did work ,hence proving that server is lisenting to port 9999

Comment: socketforClient = new SockClient( server_obj->nextPendingConnection())

But in header file constructor have two parameters: QObject* parent and QTcpSocket* socket, which is default 0.

Try to use:
socketforClient = new SockClient(this,  server_obj->nextPendingConnection())

Comment: Now try to use: socketClient = socket;  instead of creating new TcpSocket

Comment: Thanks . Thats works.. just out of curiousity why it didnt work when I used socketClient= new QTcpSocket( socket)

Comment: Because of default construct for QTcpSocket is: QTcpSocket::QTcpSocket ( QObject * parent = 0 ). In your case you just created new QTcpSocket which were not associated with socket descriptor of incoming connection.